# Run android IntentService/Service sequentially

Tags: android

im trying to use the Amazon S3 upload class to send files, but it only send all Async, i need to send a large amout of files but to avoid all networking data blocked because this, im looking in a way to send the files in sequence:

what im looking at:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 es.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  transferUtility = S3.getTransferUtility(getApplicationContext());
                    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(S3.BUCKET_NAME, file.getName(), file);
                    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                            if (TransferState.COMPLETED.equals(state)) {

                            }
                            Log.d(SERVICE_NAME, "[onStateChanged] ID: " + id + " --- State: " + state);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                            Log.d(SERVICE_NAME, "[onProgressChanged] ID: " + id + " --- bytesCurrent: " + bytesCurrent + " --- BytesTotal: " + bytesTotal);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d(SERVICE_NAME, "[onError] ID: " + id);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

but it still run all in parallel

is there a way to archieve this without creating a CallBack/Interface to receive when the download finishs and than start the next one?